# HTML to WordPress

Tags: html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I've never used WordPress.org before. I'm wondering if I can convert this html website that I have to wordpress exactly the same?

https://reporting.pacificamerican.org/pas/

And if this website is a wordpress site, does it means that I don't have to go into the codes if I want to update my content? Because right now with html site it takes more time to update all the contents.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you *can*, but looking at the content I wouldn't say it looks like a great idea. Mostly because of how static the current content seems to be.

Pros:

- It looks like you are about to add a blog-page. WordPress *does* make such re-occuring content easy.
- It looks like you have repeated the menu on every page. (If you change the menu on one page, then you have to makes changes to all pages as well?). WordPress would help with that and let you use one menu everywhere. But there are also tons of easier methods to accomplish the same thing without WordPress. (For example `<?php include 'menu.php';?>` using PHP).

Cons:

- The "multiple sub-pages in one page" that you are using doesn't play naturally with WordPress. Absolutely possible yes, perhaps not even difficult, but not out-of-the-box for sure.
- The time it would take to edit pages would likely not change as drastic as you hope. I believe that the current content looks so static that anyone with a bit HTML/CSS knowledge would rather want to edit those static html files over having to click around in the WordPress admin interface.
- The scroll-spy, editing tables and things like the yearly admissions does not come naturally either. I can think of a few dozen ways to solve such things with WordPress, but if you are going to do this work yourself, then the WordPress-conversion will take some effort and the results will not always be as pretty as you might imagine.
- You'll definitely take a performance hit over using only static html. (But that is true for any CMS/framework)

My suggestion would be to first look at your current workflow. Perhaps look at an IDE that can upload with a click or on save, have history so you can back up when things break, and predefined snippets that make static content changes easy, (and of course code syntax highlighting!).

What tools are you using now?

*Also remember that you are asking on a coding-site. Not many here would opt to use the WordPress editor over simply editing html-files. In fact, I dare to say many here carries a deep grudge after having to work around some specific quirks in the WP editor (aka tinyMCE).*

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you could replicate the layouts.

Sure, your content would be editable with just a form.

It would take a lot of effort, but certainly doable.